# Let $ \mathbb{K}$ be a field with 27 elements and $ a \in \mathbb{K}$. Then there exists $ x, y \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $ x^3 + y^5 = a$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{K}$  be a  field with 27  elements  and $ a \in \mathbb{K}$. Then  there  exists $ x, y \in \mathbb{K}$  such  that $ x^3 + y^5 = a$. How  to  try? Using  extensions  fields?

Comment: Try to use the fact that the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism of $K$

Comment: $5$ and $3$ are both coprime to $27-1$ so all the elements of $K$ are third as well as fifth powers giving the claim immediately.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  why?

Comment: @alexb $3$ is a prime, and does not divide $26$, $5$ is a prime, and does not divide $26$.

Comment: @alexb if $x^5=y^5$ with both $x,y$ non-zero, then $(x/y)^5=1$. By Lagrange $(x/y)^{26}=1$. Together these imply that $x/y=1$ or $x=y$. Therefore raising to the fifth power is injective. Because the field is finite, raising to fifth must also be surjective.